# Custom object as task arguments and JSON serialization/deserialization for celery 4.0

Tags: python, json, deserialization, celery

With `json` replacing `pickle` as default serializer for `celery 4.0`, I was wondering if there's still a way to use custom objects as task arguments while using the `json` serializer.

Using `pickle`, custom objects needed to implement the methods `__getstate__` for serialization and `__setstate__(state)` for deserialization.

The [what's new](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/whatsnew-4.0.html#json-is-now-the-default-serializer) section of `celery 4.0` mentions that custom objets when used as task arguments, requires the implementation of `__json__` for serialization purposes. But, there's no way to implement the deserialization method.

Am I missing something?